# Copy filtered data from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the filtered data from a table on sht1 to sht2 (which does not have a table). This works fine using the following code. The problem I encounter, it always copies all the data from the table on sht1 to sht2. What I am looking for is a way to copy only the filtered data to sht2. I looked up several similar questions, but (with my very limited knowledge) I am not able to implement them in my code. Any help is much appreciated.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Range("A2:P100").ClearContents
   Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DRIVE input form")
   Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dowlex 2023")
   If sht2.Range("C1").Value = "" Then Exit Sub

   Dim lastRow As Long
   sht1.Range("F2:F100").Value = sht2.Range("C2:C100").Value
   sht1.Range("G2:G100").Value = sht2.Range("E2:E100").Value
   sht1.Range("K2:K100").Value = sht2.Range("F2:F100").Value
   sht1.Range("M2:M100").Value = sht2.Range("G2:G100").Value
   sht1.Range("J2:J100").Value = sht2.Range("A2:A100").Value
   sht1.Range("P2:P100").Value = sht2.Range("H2:H100").Value
   sht1.Range("N2:N100").Value = sht2.Range("I2:I100").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Check on "Filter copy/paste Visible Cells"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SpecialCells to get only visible rows:

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("filtered")
    
    CopyVisibleValues wsSrc.Range("A2:A200"), wsDest.Range("B2")
    CopyVisibleValues wsSrc.Range("B2:B200"), wsDest.Range("A2")
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub



Sub CopyVisibleValues(rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range)
    Dim rngVis As Range
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no visible rows
    Set rngVis = rngSrc.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors
    
    If Not rngVis Is Nothing Then
        rngVis.Copy
        rngDest.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Else
        Debug.Print "No visible cells in " & rngSrc.Address(False, False)
    End If
End Sub
```